# Custom WIM image to be deployed through SCCM 2007 r2

Tags: windows-7, deployment, image, sccm, wim

I have captured a WIM file using imagex. It is windows 7 with a few apps that wouldnt install properly.
I now want to deploy this through SCCM but for some reason it keeps failing. When it loads the WinPE it reboots shortly afterward.
The last error i got was error code 0x80040104.
I wouldnt think it wold be so difficult. Is there a way that this can be done.
The image has already been sysprepped so i basically just want to deploy the image as is and rename the machines to a naming convention.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in this forum.
http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1660-customising-windows-7-deployments-part-1/
it worked for me.